# Ping-pong value decreasing over time for flickering effect

Tags: math, language-agnostic, trigonometry, game-development

[image: graph]

I need a function like this. Horizontal value is the time, and vertical is the output. Starting at time `0`, the value should be `-1` or `1`. Increasing the amount of time, the value should go to `1` and `-1`, decreasing the distance each time it "bounces".

I have done it in the past with hackish code: storing in a variable the target value, and every time the value reaches the target value, I do `targetValue *= -.5`, and so on.

Maybe there's a better implementation using a mathematical function out there that doesn't require doing this by hand. For me, it's like a trigonometric function but the final output is multiplied by `1 - (time / maxTime)`, and it's not a wave but lines.

Comment: Closest function that I can think of would be `-cos(n*x) * (max - x) / max`: [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%60-cos%2810x%29+*+%285+-+x%29+%2F+5%60+from+x+%3D+0+to+5). If you really need it to be a triangle wave, use an approximation and dampen it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was for the **flickering** effect for a game (so the character being hit starts to flicker slowly and then flickers more quickly), I ended up making a solution based on @Blender answer.

[image: Wolfram Alpha Plot]

The only difference is that apart from making the **vertical** bouncing separation smaller, it also makes the **horizontal** bouncing separation smaller.

The code in **AS3** would be:

```
// flickerTime is a Number between 0 and max, in seconds.
// max is the amount in seconds that the flickering effect lasts
// 10 is a constant that can be changed if we want more or less flickers in that amount of time
var max:Number = 3;
var flick:Number = Math.cos(this.flickerTime * this.flickerTime * 10) * (max - this.flickerTime) / max;
this.visible = flick > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in the exact shape, then `targetValue *= -.5` is exactly what I would do, as long as the time increments between calls to the function which draws the graph are equal.  The reason that I think that's a good choice is that it's the simplest choice that will do what you want.  If the time increments are unequal you might want to have something proportional to -(time-Increment) instead of always -.5.

Answer (score 1):

If the decrease of the "target value" is linear, as in your figure, then:

- Normalize your time steps to 1 and let the number of normalized periods needed to get to 0 be n.
- Start with targetValue = -1,
- There are terser ways to write the code, but here is a clear version. It is written in SAS OPTMODEL code, but if you don't have access to OPTMODEL you should be able to translate it to any language easily:

  ```
  proc optmodel;
  num targetValue init -1;
  num n init 3;
  num series{ t in 1 .. 2*n + 1} = 
      if t = 1 then 
          targetValue
      else 
          -series[t - 1] + mod(t,2)* (1 / n);
  print series;
  quit;
  ```

If you use a product by a constant instead of a subtraction by a constant your series will reach 0 only in the limit.